# Should I split my questions up, if they are all small questions about the same editorial?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, questions

I am reading an article written in French. I have many questions that I cannot answer for myself using tools available to me (eg, my grammar understanding, plus dictionaries, plus google).

Many of these questions, though, are "small" and likely don't require long answers or much discussion to clarify. (This is in contrast to the more "grammar"-based questions that I tend to ask).

Should I split each question I have about the article into its own post on french.stackexchange ? Or should I combine all my questions into one post?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely split it into several questions and check for each one if it fits our [acceptability policy](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).